# Is Unique Thread Id guaranteed for each Kernel Call in CUDA?

Tags: indexing, cuda, nvidia, pycuda

I have recently started to work with Cuda, I have multithread, multiprocess coding experience on C++, Java and Python.

With PyCuda I see example codes like this,

```py
ker = SourceModule("""
__global__ void scalar_multiply_kernel(float *outvec, float scalar, float *vec)
{
     int i = threadIdx.x;
     outvec[i] = scalar*vec[i];
}
""")
```

It seems the thread id itself partakes in the logic of the code. Then the question is will there be enough thread ids covering my entire array (whose indexing I apparently need to reach all elements there), and what happens if I change the size of the array.

Will the indexing always be between 0 and N?

Comment: In short no. There is extensive documentation on how this works in the first few pages of the programming guide https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#thread-hierarchy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In CUDA the thread id is only unique per so-called thread block, meaning, that your example kernel only does the right thing with only one block doing work. This is probably done in early examples to ease you into the ideas, but it is generally a very bad thing to do in terms of performance:

With one block, you can only utilize one of many streaming multiprocessors (SMs) in a GPU and even that SM will only be able to hide memory access latencies when it has enough parallel work to do while waiting.

A single thread-block also limits you in the number of threads and therefore in the problem-size, if your kernel doesn't contain a loop so every thread can compute more than one element.

Kernel execution is seen strongly hierarchically: Restricting ourselves to one dimensional indexing for simplicity, a kernel is executed on a so-called grid of `gridDim.x` thread blocks, each containing `blockDim.x` threads numbered per block by `threadIdx.x`, while each block is numbered via `blockIdx.x`.

To get a unique ID for a thread (in a fashion that ideally uses the hardware to load elements from an array), you have to take `blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x`. If more than one element shall be computed by every thread, you use a loop of the form

```c
for (int i = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x; i < InputSize; i += gridDim.x * blockDim.x) { 
/* ... */
}
```

This is called a grid-stride loop, because `gridDim.x * blockDim.x` is the number of all threads working on the kernel. Different strides (especially having a thread working on consecutive elements: stride = 1) might work, but will be much slower due to the non-ideal memory access pattern.